# PyDictionary Synoyms and Antonyms Problem

Tags: python, pydictionary

Trying to use pyDictionary, but there is a problem with the commands **synonyms** and **antonyms**...

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary=PyDictionary()
print (dictionary.synonym("Life"))
```

This error appears

```
Life has no Synonyms in the API
None
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: It's a known issue with the package https://github.com/geekpradd/PyDictionary/issues/49

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a feature request, not a programming question.

Comment: Oh alright , perhaps I'll try another module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyDictionary isn't actively maintained, so I would recommend looking at alternative packages.

I'm the author of the Python package [WordHoard](https://pypi.org/project/wordhoard).  This package can be used to find semantic relationships between words including a word's antonyms, synonyms, hypernyms, hyponyms and homophones.

- [GitHub WordHoard](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/wordhoard)
- [WordHoard documentation](https://wordhoard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from wordhoard import Synonyms

word = 'life'
results = Synonyms(search_string=word, output_format='json').find_synonyms()
print(results)
{
    "synonyms": {
        "life": [
            "activity",
            "aliveness",
            "animation",
            "being",
            "bio",
            "biography",
            "breath",
            "brio",
            "dash",
            "energy",
            "enthusiasm",
            "entity",
            "esprit",
            "essence",
            "excitement",
            "experience",
            "get-up-and-go",
            "go",
            "growth",
            "heart",
            "high spirits",
            "impulse",
            "life history",
            "life sentence",
            "life story",
            "life-time",
            "lifeblood",
            "lifespan",
            "lifetime",
            "liveliness",
            "living",
            "memoir",
            "oomph",
            "sentience",
            "soul",
            "sparkle",
            "spirit",
            "sprightliness",
            "verve",
            "viability",
            "vigor",
            "vitality",
            "vivacity",
            "zest",
            "zing",
            "élan",
            "élan vital"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add `OneLook Thesaurus` data? For example: https://www.onelook.com/thesaurus/?s=active , with some way to retain the subclasses split and retrieval and the order (All, Adjective, Nous, Verbs, Adverbs, Idioms/Slang, Old), and possibly the filters, for example the `most funny sounding` https://www.onelook.com/thesaurus/?s=active&sortby=hu1 More details here: https://www.onelook.com/thesaurus/?s=active#help
https://datamuse.com/api/ https://www.youtube.com/@datamuse

Comment: I can look into adding this source to WordHoard.  Adding a source requires some research and testing, so I don't know the time frame to complete these tasks.  I have looked at adding Parts of Speech, but I need to adding some filtering in the code base.  This is something in the pipeline for development.  I will post back here when I have done some research into OneLook Thesaurus.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. They have 2 apis but I'm not yet familiar with it. For example: https://www.onelook.com/api/words?ml=active&qe=ml&md=dpfcy&max=850&rif=1&k=olthes_r4
The second api:
https://www.datamuse.com/api/
Also a short overview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgPwm4FstXw Also those github hits might be of value: https://github.com/scalarwaves/leximaven https://github.com/howdyAnkit/Datamuse_apiWord-

Comment: I looked at the API info and it seems that the pull from WordNet.  I already have the source in the code base for WordHoard.   I need to do some research to see what  Onelook has that can enhance WordHoard's capabilities.

Comment: Their source is from 1061 dictionaries (18,955,870 words in 1061 dictionaries indexed), from their `Dictionary` app on the onelook.com domain : https://onelook.com/ . Their `Thesaurus` is here https://onelook.com/thesaurus/ . Can you add the `Thesaurus` data? For a full presentation : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcednTikRLk&t=1s